# Find basis $\mathcal B$ such that Gram matrix is of specific form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $K$ be a field with $1+1\neq 0$, $V$ be a vector space over $K$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle:V\times V\rightarrow K$ an alternating bilinear form.
Use following fact

- $v\in V \setminus V^{\perp}\Rightarrow \exists v'\in V:\langle v,v' \rangle=1\text{ and }V=span(v,v')\oplus span(v,v')^{\perp} $

to find basis $\mathcal B$ of $\mathbb Q^4$ over the field $\mathbb Q$ such that Gram matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0& -3& 1& -3\\
3&0&-3&1\\
-1&3&0&0\\
3&-1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$ of a standard basis has the form 
$\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1& 0& 0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&-1&0
\end{pmatrix}$ of basis $\mathcal B$.

Comment: So, what’s your question?

Comment: @amd I am looking for small hint.